# Java array changing untouched values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a genetic algorithm which recreates paintings using triangles. At the moment my method used to populate children is changing the values of the parents and I can't figure out why.

```
public void populate()
{
    System.out.println("pre: " + Arrays.toString(triangles[0][0]));
    for(int drawNum = 2; drawNum < 12; drawNum ++)
    {
        for(int triNum = 0; triNum < numTriangles; triNum ++)
        {
            double pChooser = Math.random();
            if(pChooser < .45)
            {
                triangles[drawNum][triNum] = triangles[0][triNum];
            }
            else if(pChooser < .9)
            {
                triangles[drawNum][triNum] = triangles[1][triNum];
            }
            else
            {
                triangles[drawNum][triNum] = randomTriangle();
            }
        }
    }
    genNum ++;
    System.out.println("pst: " + Arrays.toString(triangles[0][0]));
}

private int[] randomTriangle()
{
    int[] result = new int[9];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        result[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    }
    return result;
}
```

`triangles` is a 3 dimensional int array that holds each drawing, each triangle in the drawing, and each value of the endpoints and color of the triangle in the form `triangles[drawingNumber][triangleNumber][values]`. `triangles[0]` and `triangles[1]` are the two parents. The print statements print the values of the first triangle in the first parent before and after the children are formed. However, the pre and post print statements are returning different results, meaning that `triangles[0][0]` was changed somewhere in the code, but I can't figure out where that is.

Comment: What is the type of the elements in the `triangles` array?

Comment: triangles is a int[][][]. It holds the current values of the parents and children. @Carcigenicate

Comment: Given the indices of your loops, it doesn't seem possible for `triangles[0][0]` to be assigned another `int[]` array in these loops, so it must be the same array. Is it possible that your `randomTriangle()` method writes in an existing `triangles[i][j]` array?

Comment: Can you post the code of `randomTriangle()`? Does it write to `triangles` at all?

Comment: @Joffrey `randomTriangle()` simply creates and returns an `int[]` which contains values for the new triangle

Comment: How is `triangles` generated?

Comment: @Ishamael the first parents are randomly generated and the rest are populated using `populate()`

Comment: I guess my question was how the array is created to begin with, not how the values are computed

Comment: @Ishamael it's a public global variable, created as `public int[][][] triangles = new int[12][numTriangles][9]`

Comment: Two more questions: is everything single threaded, and do you ever change lowest level elements of `triangles` (i.e. triangles[a][b][c])

Comment: @JoshCzopek it looks like there is simply not enough information for us to help you. Try to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see what happens. Here, if everything is single threaded, if we remove `genNum ++;` and if we add the `triangles` initialization, it looks like we have a minimal working code. Does that reproduce your issue (being, the 2 print statements print different things)?